Email is not adding [ and ] bracket in VBA for Json format
I have below function which is formatting my JSON, but email is not being formatted the way I like.
Current output for email is like this:
"emails": "TestEmail1@test.com",

but I am looking for this format instead:
"emails":[  
    {  
        "value":"testsac1@merck.com",
        "type":"work",
        "primary":true
    }
],

How do I fix the code in VBA ?
Function GetRequestBody(requestType As String, Optional includeOptional As Boolean = False) As Object
    Dim requestBody As Object
    Set requestBody = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If LCase(requestType) = "http return" Then
        requestBody("status") = "<HTTP STATUS CODE>"
        requestBody("raw") = "<JSON>"
        requestBody("message") = "<HTTP RESPONSE>"
        Set GetRequestBody = requestBody
        Exit Function
    ElseIf LCase(requestType) = "create user" Then
        requestBody("schemas") = Array("ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User", "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User")
        requestBody("userName") = "<REQ ID>"
        Set requestBody("name") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With requestBody("name")
            .Add "givenName", "<FIRST NAME>"
            .Add "familyName", "<LAST NAME>"
        End With
        requestBody("displayName") = "<DISPLAY NAME>"
        Set requestBody("emails") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With requestBody("emails")
            .Add "value", "<WORK EMAIL>"
            .Add "type", "work"
            .Add "primary", "true"
        End With
        
        Set requestBody("roles") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set requestBody("groups") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set requestBody("urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With requestBody("urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0")
            Set .Item("manager") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .Item("manager")("managerId") = "<MANAGER ID>"
        End With

        If includeOptional Then
            Set requestBody("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:user-custom-parameters:1.0") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With requestBody("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:user-custom-parameters:1.0")
                .Add "dataAccessLanguage", "en"
                .Add "dateFormatting", "MMM d, yyyy"
                .Add "timeFormatting", "H:mm:ss"
                .Add "numberFormatting", "1,234.56"
                .Add "cleanUpNotificationsNumberOfDays", 0
                .Add "systemNotificationsEmailOptIn", "true"
                .Add "marketingEmailOptIn", "false"
                .Add "isConcurrent", "true"
            End With
        End If
    ElseIf LCase(requestType) = "create team" Then
        requestBody("id") = "<TEAM ID>"
        requestBody("displayName") = "<TEAM DESC>"
        Set requestBody("members") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With requestBody("members")
            .Add "type", "User"
            .Add "value", " <USER ID> "
            .Add "$ref", "/api/v1/scim/Users/<USER ID> "
        End With
        Set requestBody("roles") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        If includeOptional Then
            Set requestBody("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:group-custom-parameters:1.0") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With requestBody("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:sap:group-custom-parameters:1.0")
                .Add "admins", Array("User1")
                .Add "moderators", Array("User1", "User2")
            End With
        End If
    ElseIf LCase(requestType) = "add user" Then
        requestBody("type") = "User"
        requestBody("value") = " <USER ID> "
        requestBody("$ref") = "/api/v1/scim/Users/<USER ID>"
    ElseIf LCase(requestType) = "add team" Then
        requestBody("value") = "<TEAM ID>"
        requestBody("display") = "<TEAM TEXT>"
        requestBody("$ref") = "/api/v1/scim/Groups/<TEAM ID>"
    ElseIf LCase(requestType) = "add email" Then
        requestBody("value") = "<EMAIL>"
        requestBody("type") = "<TYPE>"
        requestBody("primary") = "<VALUE>"
    End If

    Set GetRequestBody = requestBody
End Function


Using Tim Hall's JSON tool; (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)
Sub TestJSON()
    Dim data As Dictionary, email As Dictionary, strJSON As String

    Set data = New Dictionary
    Set email = New Dictionary
    
    With data
        .Add "value", "testsac1@merck.com"
        .Add "type", "work"
        .Add "primary", True
    End With
    
    email.Add "emails", data

    strJSON = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(ByVal email)

    MsgBox strJSON
End Sub

The result is;
{"emails":{"value":"testsac1@merck.com","type":"work","primary":true}}

Or, if you need to add an array of emails then use something like this.
Obviously, you may need to revise the method for adding dictionary data to the collection, as this is just a sample to show the mechanism.
 Sub TestJSON2()
    Dim data As Dictionary, email As Collection, JSON_data As Dictionary, strJSON As String

    Set email = New Collection
    
    Set data = New Dictionary
    
    With data
        .Add "value", "testsac1@merck.com"
        .Add "type", "work"
        .Add "primary", True
    End With
    
    email.Add data
    
    Set data = New Dictionary
    
    With data
        .Add "value", "sac1@merck.com"
        .Add "type", "Home"
        .Add "primary", False
    End With
    
    email.Add data
    
    Set data = New Dictionary
    
    With data
        .Add "value", "admin@merck.com"
        .Add "type", "work"
        .Add "primary", True
    End With
    
    email.Add data
    
    Set JSON_data = New Dictionary
    JSON_data.Add "emails", email
    
    strJSON = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(ByVal JSON_data, 2)

    MsgBox strJSON
End Sub


The result is given below;
{"emails":[{"value":"testsac1@merck.com","type":"work","primary":true},{"value":"sac1@merck.com","type":"Home","primary":false},{"value":"admin@merck.com","type":"work","primary":true}]}

